# Sharepoint 2013 - Only domain admins can open PDFs

Tags: pdf

We had an issue last week with our users getting pop-up prompts for permissions when trying to save Office 2013 documents from our SharePoint server.

The fix I implemented was to

> Go into IIS, select the site, go under Request Filtering, and added OPTIONS: False and PROPFIND: False.

This made the prompt disappear in Office docs.  Now the users can't open PDFs.  They get a pop-up window from Adobe (Acrobat or Reader):

> There was an error opening this document. "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

I and the other domain admin do NOT get this prompt, the document opens without issue.

Seems to be a rights issue, but the only thing I've changed in the past while was the reference at the start of the post.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue related to having pdfs (and office docs) as editable files. We had this issue with excel docs. One workaround that I found online was to use the download.aspx to parse the excel doc links so that they look like this:

original link to excel doc: `http://mysitedotcom/pathtosite/Documents/excel.xlsx`

parsed and modified URL:

```
 http://mysitedotcom/pathtosite/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=/pathtosite/Documents/excel.xlsx&FldUrl=&Source=http://mysitedotcom/pathtosite/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

This enabled our users to bypass the login prompt on SP2013 for excel docs and provided them with a download prompt instead.

Here is the script I made so that any excel doc that gets linked gets parsed into this automatically:
Begins the function to search all the hrefs for XLS or XLSX files:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('a[href$=".xlsx"], a[href$=".xls"]').each(function() {.........
```

This is the main gist of the URL manipulation (14 is the number of characters of yourdomain.com before the path to the site begins:

```
if (testHTTP === 1) {
        startOfPathToSite = excelURL.indexOf("yourdomain.com") + 14;
        }
        else {
        startOfPathToSite = 0;
        }
        /* Determines the end of slicing the subsite path by finding the point before the Documents library */
        endOfPathToSite = excelURL.indexOf("/Documents/");
        /* Slices the start and end point of the subsite within the href. */
        pathToSite = excelURL.slice(startOfPathToSite, endOfPathToSite);
        /* Puts it all together in finalModifiedExcelURL. (downloadAspx, fieldURL, "/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx" are the static portions of the excel URL fix) */
        var downloadAspx = "/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=";
        var midDocPath = excelURL.slice(startOfPathToSite);
        var fieldURL = "&FldUrl=&Source=";
        var lastPart = siteDomain + pathToSite + "/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx";
        finalModifiedExcelURL = siteDomain + pathToSite + downloadAspx + midDocPath + fieldURL + lastPart;
 }
```

This basically replaces the href value that $.each() iterated on:

```
$(this).attr('href', finalModifiedExcelURL);
```

For your PDF issue, would setting a `target="_blank"` fix your PDF issue?
If so, this jquery might help:

```
$(function(){
    $('a[href$=".pdf"]').attr('target','_blank');
});
```

Anyways, hope this helps!
-Sung

Comment: Bear with me, I'm not quite sure how to implement this fix.  I believe you are completely correct in your assumption to the cause - as soon as I removed the two fixes I put in last week the PDF could be viewed, but the credential prompt reappeared.

Comment: I see two copies of download.aspx on the machine and they both are the same.  They show very little inside (and I'm not sure what to add):  

'<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %> <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Download"       %>
' @-Sung

Comment: I should have been clearer. This is for a front facing site. We have something similar to the above code in a .js file. This js file is called in a <link...> tag of our masterpages. This way, whenever someone loads any of our pages and it has excel or pdf links, this js will dynamically/on-the-fly modify the <a...> tags with the appropriate URL modifications (for excel) or a target="_blank" (for pdfs).

Comment: Oh, I see.  This is for an internal Sharepoint site.  An intranet portal.  Everyone accessing it has the appropriate permissions to access the site, and there is no anonymous access - so any code that we could plug into it to do this would be appreciated.